# update select same where clause update subset of records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, where-in

I have a query, when I run it as a select I get 1014 records. When I run it as an update it updates a varying number of the records usually less than 5.

Examples

```
Select * from Table 
where firstname ='john' 
and lastname = 'smith' 
and email='john.smith@gmail.com'
```

Returns 1014 rows

```
update Table
set meaninglesscolumn = 1
where firstname ='john' 
and lastname = 'smith' 
and email='john.smith@gmail.com'
```

After this update running this query returns 1012 (or a lower number, it keeps dropping after every run but running this +500 times is going to be a hassle)

```
Select * from Table 
where firstname ='john' 
and lastname = 'smith' 
and email='john.smith@gmail.com'
and meaninglesscolumn <> 1
```

Thanks.

UPDATE

Sorry for the confusion, the above 'select' returned 1658 records, not 1014. I ran it with the 'and meaninglesscolumn <> 1' and got 1015 (the number of records I want to update). I then ran the above 'update' and the 'select' and got 1014, I then ran the 'update' again and got 1012.

So full process...

```
Select * from Table 
where firstname ='john' 
and lastname = 'smith' 
and email='john.smith@gmail.com'
```

Returned 1658

```
Select * from Table 
where firstname ='john' 
and lastname = 'smith' 
and email='john.smith@gmail.com'
and meaninglesscolumn <> 1
```

Returned 1015

```
update Table
set meaninglesscolumn = 1
where firstname ='john' 
and lastname = 'smith' 
and email='john.smith@gmail.com'
```

Returned 1 row updated.

```
Select * from Table 
where firstname ='john' 
and lastname = 'smith' 
and email='john.smith@gmail.com'
and meaninglesscolumn <> 1
```

Returned 1014

Comment: Try to add to this clause  meaninglesscolumn != 1 in the first query.Those are the actual number of record to be updated. You may have few record where  meaninglesscolumn = 1 from the first query. Thats why the count may not be equal.

Comment: Sorry, the first select here did return a larger list, 1658. I append the 'and meaninglesscolumn <> 1' and I got 1015. When I ran it the second time I got 1014, and 1012 on the third run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use a while loop to update them all?

SELECT

while(result = fetch){
    UPDATE
}

Comment: That would work but I'd prefer to find the cause. I think I may run into this issue in a the future.

Answer (score 0):

The select query return all records.
The update query update or set only different value is found in meaninglesscolumn.
In the first case 2 record already have value 1 in meaninglesscolumn. So it update only 1012 records.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
update Table
set meaninglesscolumn = 1
where id in (
    Select id from Table 
    where firstname ='john' 
    and lastname = 'smith' 
    and email='john.smith@gmail.com'
    and meaninglesscolumn <> 1)
;
```

Comment: There is no ID column.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the SELECT statement is simply matching on FirstName, LastName and Email...nothing else! so all other columns are ignored, including MeaninglessColumn.

If you had 1000 rows and of them, 100 had MeaninglessColumn = 1 and 900 as MeaninglessColumn = 2, using FirstName, LastName and Email only in you WHERE clause, it wouldn't care how many had MeaninglessColumn = 1 or 2.  Now, in your UPDATE statement, you are updating the same number of rows as the SELECT (even if some of them already had MeaninglessColumn = 1) so your update will return the same number of rows affected as your initial SELECT (at least in MS SQL Server).  However, you are then altering your SELECT on the second attempt to now add in MeaninglessColumn <> 1.  You have done 2 things:

- Firstly, you have altered the dataset from the UPDATE so that all of the rows matching your initial SELECT have MeaninglessColumn = 1
- You have altered your SELECT to now filter even further on MeaninglessColumn <> 1, of which now none exist

As stated by priyanka-kotari, if you want to see the exact number of rows you will be affecting, you need to include the negative of what you are updating, i.e. MeaninglessColumn <> 1.

Comment: Updated for clarification. Select works as expected.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  If the data is static, i.e. non-changing by some application, then the follow will be true:

 - Total records for FirstName, LastName, Email => 1658
 - Subset of this where MeaninglessColumn <> 1 => 1015
 - Subset of this where MeaninglessColumn = 1 => 643 (assumption based on above 2)
 - Update to set MeaninglessColumn = 1; updates 1015 columns
 - Total number of records for FirstName, LastName, Email, MeaninglessColumn = 1 => 1658

Are you sure your data is not changing between running queries?